# Screen resolution in Control Panel different than Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, resolution, display-settings

**Edit2**: Control Panel resolutions are matching. Display scaling settings are matching but the image below shows the difference.

Edit: Thanks for all the help. Have made several changes based on the comments. I updated the screenshot here. It shows that there is some kind of zoom going on. Screen size and True size are different on this machine but match at 1600x900 on the other with (as far as I know) the same settings.

I am trying to make my resolution 1600x900 but it won't let me get it that high. In computer resolution setting it shows that I am at 1600x900 but when I run a resolution test online it says otherwise. Also I have 2 of the exact same machines and monitors set up side by side so it's got to be solvable. Has anyone ever seen anything like this before and have suggestions?

I have up-to-date graphics and monitor drivers, not sure what else to do.

[image: Screens]

Comment: First, why do you trust the website and not your computer dialog? Second, don't trust the website, there are too many ways the information it is querying is incorrect. Third, is there anything besides the website test that you shouldn't trust telling you the resolution is not 1600x900?

Comment: Click "Make text and other items larger or smaller" and check to make sure your display scaling is set to 100%. Also, go to the Properties for Internet Explorer -> Compatibility tab and check the settings for scaling on high-DPI displays.

Comment: I was using the website because I have 2 identical machines and monitors side by side at our front counter that have visibly different display sizes but all the settings seem to be the same. I have changed the IE zoom and it now detects at the same resolution as CP.

Comment: Edited original post with latest screenshot. Ideas?

Comment: For clarification, are the following statements correct for BOTH computers?  Control Panel resolution is 1600x900.  Control Panel, Display is 100%. Internet Explorer zoom is 100%.  Internet Explorer is maximized.  Finally, Resolution Inspector shows different numbers on one computer.

Comment: Control Panel shows 1600x900 for both. Display is 100% for both. IE has been adjusted. I updated the screenshot to show the difference. With the same setting one has much smaller text.

Answer (score 4):

In Internet Explorer, zooming affects the detected screen resolution.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0 (zero)</kbd> to reset the zoom to 100%.

The webpage [Resolution Inspector](http://dev.jeffersonscher.com/resolution.html) will calculate your true resolution, regardless of zoom level.

Comment: Damn. That straightened it out so now the test says the same as the control panel. Is there a general zoom setting? The 2 machines have noticeably different display sizings. I'll go grab a pair of screen shots to illustrate the difference

Comment: Check the Control Panel item called Display which contains the text scaling setting.

Comment: Thanks for that link Steven. Both machines show 1600x900. I will check the display scaling settings

Comment: The text scaling settings were indeed different, however my problem is now reversed lol. I adjusted the machine that was showing as larger down to 100% from 125% and it now appears much smaller than the other machine.

Comment: Edited original post with latest screenshot. Ideas? Sorry for re-posting this below, not sure who will get notifications from which comment sections.